# Создание XMLInputFactory StAX

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, primefaces, websphere

Делаю веб приложение на jsf primefaces. Сервер WebSphere. Создаю woodstox StAX StreamReader:

```
XMLInputFactory2 factory = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader2 reader = (XMLStreamReader2) factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFileName));
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ClassCastException: выполните следующие действия: преобразовать com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.wssec.WSSXMLInputFactory (id=1817) в org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2

Если я выполняю такой же код в обычном java приложении то ошибки не возникает. Почему newInstance создает неправильный экземпляр?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно в WebSphere Application Server EAR приложению и `.WAR` файлу поставить режим загрузчика классов `PARENT_LAST`. Все заработало=). Ошибка была из-за того, что в ibm.jar альтернативная реализация библиотеки StAX.

Answer (score 0):

Еще одно решение, чтобы быть независимым от того, как и где будет запущено приложение.

Код:

```
String className = "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory";
Class factoryClass = Class.forName(className);
XMLInputFactory factory = (XMLInputFactory)factoryClass.newInstance();
reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));
```